# Generar un sonido de varias frecuencias en Processing

Tags: java, processing

En Processing existe una librería oficial que te permite hacer sonidos mediante osciladores de seno, osciladores cuadrados, triangulares, etc.
El problema es que yo estoy intentando crear un sonido que es el resultado de combinar varias frecuencias con distintas amplitudes, es decir, un sonido que no puede ser representado de ninguna manera con las opciones que me da Processing.

Explicación visual:
La suma del sonido 1 (azul, forma de seno) más el sonido dos (rojo, forma de seno) da un resultado que no se puede imitar en Processing con la librería oficial (verde, el resultado no tiene forma de seno).

[image]

¿Existe alguna manera de generar sonidos como ese (el verde) en Processing? Dudo mucho que sea posible con la librería oficial de sondio, ya que (como he dicho antes), solo soporta un número limitado de "formas" para las funciones de sonido. ¿Pero existe la posibilidad de hacerlo mediante otra librería u otra solución? (He estado buscando librerías pero no he visto ninguna que deje hacer esto exacto).

Muchas gracias de antemano.